# Is Princess Snake based on folklore?

Tags: culture, dragon-ball-z, boruto

While watching ***Dragon Ball Z*** recently I noticed that the premise of the episode *Princess Snake* is undoubtedly similar to an episode of ***Boruto*** (which I don't think has aired in English yet).

Both episodes feature snakes disguised as attractive and unreasonably hospitable women who plan to prey on their guests. I don't feel like I can explain it well enough, but if you watch both episodes I think you'll understand why I feel like there is probably some well defined cultural context that the writers derived their works from, like a folk legend or a popular work of fiction.

I tried Googling to find out but I only found stuff about snakes with human-female heads and snake-brides. I'm very curious and its really bugging me that I can't figure this out. Does anyone here know if or what the snake-hostess narrative is based on? I imagine that there are other shows that have used the same plot that I'm not aware of.

P.S. From looking on the Naruto Wiki, I think the Boruto episode is #75, but I don't remember for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The archetype is most likely based off the [nure-onna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nure-onna) from Japanese mythology, that have the head of a woman and body of a snake and is know to be able to shapeshift and prey on people